# Using range-based for loop with a third-party container

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, iterator, boost-iterators

I'm currently using a third-party library which contains a class that only provides indexed lookup, i.e. `operator[]`.

I'd like to do a range-based for loop on this class's contents. However, having never written an iterator or iterator adapter, I'm quite lost. It seems that writing iterators is not a straightforward task.

My desired usage is:

```
for(auto element : container)
{
    ...
}
```

Instead of having to write:

```
for(int i = 0; i < container.size(); ++i)
{
    auto element = container[i];
    ...
}
```

How can this be achieved? Does Boost provide this functionality?

Comment: I recommend you read [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), it might give you some hints what you need.

Comment: This [link](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) helps me understand quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing iterators is actually a rather straightforward task, but it gets extremely tedious. Since your container supports indexing by an integer, I assume its iterators would fall into the random access iterator category (if they existed). That needs a lot of boilerplate!

However, to support the range-based for loop, all you'll need is a forward iterator. We'll write a simple wrapper for the container that implements the forward iterator requirements, and then write two functions `Iterator begin(Container&)` and `Iterator end(Container&)` that enable the container to be used in the range-based for loop.

This `Iterator` will contain a reference to the container, the size of the container, and the current index within that container:

```
template<template<typename> class C, typename T>
class indexer : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator, T>
{
public:
    indexer(C<T>& c, std::size_t i, std::size_t end)
        : c_(std::addressof(c)), i_(i), end_(end) {}

    T& operator*() const {
        return c_[i_];
    }

    indexer<C, T>& operator++() {
        ++i_;
        return *this;
    }
    indexer<C, T> operator++(int) {
        auto&& tmp = *this;
        operator++();
        return tmp;
    }

    bool operator==(indexer<C, T> const& other) const {
        return i_ == other.i_;
    }
    bool operator!=(indexer<C, T> const& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

private:
    C<T>* c_;
    std::size_t i_, end_;
};
```

Inheriting from `std::iterator` conveniently declares the appropriate typedefs for use with `std::iterator_traits`.

Then, you would define `begin` and `end` as follows:

```
template<typename T>
indexer<Container, T> begin(Container<T>& c) {
    return indexer<Container, T>(c, 0, c.size());
}

template<typename T>
indexer<Container, T> end(Container<T>& c) {
    auto size = c.size();
    return indexer<Container, T>(c, size, size);
}
```

Switch out `Container` for whatever the type of `container` is in your example, and with that, your desired usage works!

The requirements and behavior of all the various kinds of iterators can be found in the tables of section 24.2.2 of the standard, which are mirrored at [cppreference.com here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept#Iterator).

A random-access iterator implementation of the above, along with a demo of usage with a simple `vector_view` class can be found live on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b48235bcb61cbb8a) or [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/aYHbYT).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1) define your own iterator `It` that contains, inside, a ref `ref` to your container `container` and an index `i`. When the iterator is dereferenced, it returns `ref[i]` by reference. You can write it yourself or you can use boost for help, it has an iterator library to easily define your own iterators. Constructor should accept a `container&` and a `size_t`. You can make also the `const_iterator` if this concept applies.

2) When `operator++` is invoked on one iterator, it simply does `++i` on the internal member. `operator==` and `operator!=` should simply compare `i`. You can `assert`, for security, that both iterators are coherent, that means their `ref`s point to the same object.

3) add `begin` and `end` to your container class or, if this is not possible, define a global `begin` and `end` that accept your `container& c`. `begin` should simply return `It(c, 0)`. `end` should return `It(c, c.size())`.

There could be a problem copying the iterators as they contain a reference and some other minor details, but I hope the overall idea is clear and correct.